# user defined function in r: object not found

Tags: r, function

I have created a custom function in R, I want to do a cox model basing on some user input, my actual formula is this

```
coxmodel <- function(time= time, status = status, covariate = covariate, dataset = dataset) {

modellocox <- eval(parse(text = paste("coxph(Surv(", time, ", ", status, "==2) ~", covariate, ", data=", dataset)))
testproporz <- cox.zph(modellocox)
}
```

However i get this error message

```
Error in paste("coxph(Surv(", time, ", ", status, "==2) ~", covariate,  : 
object "age" not found
```

how can i create a function which takes string user input and creates formulas based on that?

Comment: What's the objective here, why do you have to pass it `eval(parse`... instead of the actual `coxph` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined value of age in `paste("coxph(Surv(", time, ", ", status, "==2) ~", covariate,` `R` is searching for its value.